# Can I deploy jdbc spec3 compliant driver to JBoss 6 without adding java.sql.Driver file?

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss

I realized that I need to add /META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file to jdbc driver jar(when only supports spec3) file in order to deploy to JBoss 6.

And I want to know there is a any way except adding java.sql.Driver file manually to my jdbc driver file.
Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: try adding it to to a separate jar

Comment: How did you realize that you need to add it? Does JBoss refuse to deploy otherwise? If so, what error does it produce? BTW: What driver are you using that it doesn't implement JDBC 4.x?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, when I tried to deploy original jar, Jboss refused to deploy and javax.naming..NameNotFoundException occured. And after I added java.sql.Driver file manually, that problem was solved. Unfortunately jdbc driver which I using is not support JDBC 4.0 Spec.